# How can I install Microsoft Bluetooth Stack on my laptop?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, toshiba-laptop

The Toshiba Bluetooth Stack is giving me a hard time to manage and I want to switch to Microsoft's. My netbook uses Microsoft's and I am fine with it. How can I install it on my laptop? I followed this [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34584) but I was only able to download a PowerPoint presentation.

Comment: The page you link to in your question states "Supported Operating System Windows XP" so is not applicable to Windows 7 anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming Toshiba didn't strip out the Windows bluetooth stack or something crazy like that, this should do it:

1. Open the Device Manager.
2. Open the properties dialog for your Bluetooth adapter.
3. Click the "Update driver" button under the "Driver" tab.
4. Select the option for browsing your computer for a driver.
5. Select the option for choosing from a list.
6. Pick the Microsoft Bluetooth stack (should be called "Generic Bluetooth Adapter").